# How to convert short array to BitSet with 2 bit precision in Java?

Tags: java, bytebuffer, bitset

I have a short array `{0,2,3,1,…}` which I would like to convert to a BitSet.

Expected bits in bitset: `00 10 11 01 …`

Every two bit in the bitset should represent a short. (2-bit precision)
This should work fine for short values (0,1,2,3).

I know that I can use `ByteBuffer` and `BitSet` to access the bits of the numbers but those are formatted into 2 bytes (16 bit). I assume I need to bitshift the values to access the correct bits but I don't know how.

```java
int nBit = 0;
BitSet result = new BitSet();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
  buffer.putShort(number);
  BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(buffer.array());

  result.set(nBit++, bits.get(?));
  result.set(nBit++, bits.get(?));
}
```

It there maybe an easier way?

Comment: Why not use a byte instead of a BitSet? You only need 8 bits...

Comment: The array is not limited to 4 numbers. I have updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Have you seen `BitSet.valueOf(byte[] bytes)` or `BitSet.valueOf(long[] longs)`?

Answer (score 0):

My current pragmatic solution which may be okay since only 4 values need to be handled:

```java
public static BitSet transformToBitSet(short[] numbers) {
        BitSet data = new BitSet();
        int nBit = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            short number = numbers[i];
            switch (number) {
            case 0:
                data.set(nBit++, false);
                data.set(nBit++, false);
                break;
            case 1:
                data.set(nBit++, true);
                data.set(nBit++, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                data.set(nBit++, false);
                data.set(nBit++, true);
                break;
            case 3:
                data.set(nBit++, true);
                data.set(nBit++, true);
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid number encountered. Can't map values >4");
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Your bits are backwards. 1 should have the lowest bit set, and 2 should have the second bit set.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I tested this via `Integer.parseInt("01", 2) == 1`

Comment: `parseInt()` reads the most significant digit first. In `01`, `1` is the low bit and `0` is the high bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

- set the desired bitLength (used for padding on the left with zero bits);
- initialize the BitSet index to 0.
- The iterate over the values.
- convert each to a bit string.
- pad on the left to achieve the desired bit length
- then set the bits based on the numeric value of the bit

```
BitSet b = new BitSet();
short[] vals = { 0, 2, 3, 1 };


int bitLength = 2;
int idx = 0;
for (short v : vals) {
    String bits = Integer.toBinaryString(v);
    bits = "0".repeat(bitLength - bits.length())+bits;
    for (char c : bits.toCharArray()) {
        b.set(idx++, c - '0' == 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(b)
```

prints

```
2,4,5,7
```