# How to convert BitSet -> short array with 4 bit precision?

Tags: java, bitset

I want to convert the `BitSet` data of variable length to an array of shorts.

`BitSet` -> `short[]`

Every four bits of the bitset should be used to construct a new number.

Example data:

```java
BitSet bits = new BitSet();

// 1101 = 13
bits.set(0, true);
bits.set(1, true);
bits.set(2, false);
bits.set(3, true);

// 0011 = 3
bits.set(4, false);
bits.set(5, false);
bits.set(6, true);
bits.set(7, true);
…

short[] numbers = …
```

Comment: Can you explain why `bits.toByteArray()` is not good for you?

Comment: I need the numbers for further processing. Using bytes will not work since those will map to 8 bit.

Comment: I consider `short` being a number... What about `bits.toLongArray()`? What 4-bit precision means as you wrote "variable length"?

Comment: Why to ask multiple times? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658220/how-to-convert-short-array-to-bitset-with-2-bit-precision-in-java

Comment: That's the other way around and deals with 4 bit precision. IMHO different question, different scope.

Comment: Your bits are backwards again. `1101 = 13`

Comment: @shmosel Thanks, I was wondering how is 0011 bigger than 1101...

Comment: Where? The direction of the conversion is a totally different one. Please read carefully before closing.

Comment: @Jotschi  You're right!  My apologies.  Reopened.

Comment: Why four bits in a short?  Four bits is half a byte.

Comment: I could also have used a byte. Java does not have a primitive data type for 4 bits. The bitset data contains numbers which are encoded in 4 bit each. I want to extract those.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution. A new bitset will be populated with the bits of the source and toLongArray() can be used to return the value.

```
public static short toShort4Bit(BitSet bits, int offset) {
    BitSet bitset = new BitSet(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        bitset.set(i, bits.get(offset+i));
    }
    return (short) bitset.toLongArray()[0];
}
```

Comment: Why to copy it to new BitSet? Why is `bitset.toByteArray()[0]` not enough (I believe that cast to short is not needed)... You didn't reply if you need 4 bits or variable length...

Comment: This would utilize 8 bits of the source bitset. I want only to take the next 4 bits into account when generating the short number. If I use `bitset.toByteArray()[0]` it will use 8 bits and this will return a different number.

Comment: I didn't expect that, so shift it by 4 bits: `bitset.toByteArray()[0] >> 4`, so you'll make 4 out of 8...

Comment: Yes that could work. In my tests I get 00001101 for the byte and this is -80 when cast to short. I need 10110000 . The endianness does not match. Is there a quick way to fix this?

Comment: That will reverse the byte order but not the bits in the single byte. I have tried it. I have now chosen a different route which does not involve converting to shorts. Thanks for your effort.